# Should this has_many :through relationship be polymorphic or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a many-to-many relationship setup for `Teachers` and `Classrooms` via `has_many :through`:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms, :through => :classroom_memberships
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :teachers, :through => :classroom_memberships
end

class ClassroomMemberships < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :classroom
end
```

Currently, `Students` can only belong to one `Classroom`:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
end
```

Now I have the need to track historical classroom memberships for students, creating a second many-to-many relationship for classrooms. So, while a student can only belong to one classroom at a time, I need to know that last year, student A belonged to classroom B.

I'm thinking I have two viable options:

1.) Make the `classroom_memberships` association polymorphic so I'd have a `classroomable_id` and `classroomable_type` that would point to either a teacher OR a student.

2.) Simplify things and add another foreign key to `ClassroomMemberships` called `student_id`, in which case, for a given row, either `student_id` OR `teacher_id` would have a value.

Which is the better option?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go the route of:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  # like "MATH 100"
  has_many :sections
  has_many :teachers, :through => :sections
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  # like "Fall 2015"
  has_many :sections
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  has_many :courses, :through => :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  # a course, in a term, taught by a teacher, with registered students
  belongs_to :term
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :students, :through => :registrations
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  # a student in a specific section
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :student 
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # a student's registrations are their course history
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :sections, through :registrations
end
```

As a start, since this is a fairly basic modeling of an educational system.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you want a ClassroomMembershipHistory model.

Something like

```
class ClassroomMembershipHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :classroom
end
```

with a `year` attribute, stored however is easiest to query for your use case.

Comment: Hmm, but would you make the key that references the student/teacher polymorphic? Or would you add two keys (`parent_id`, `teacher_id`)?

Comment: Do you also need historical classroom data for teachers? Your question indicated that only students needed to have their memberships logged.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The `ClassroomMemberships` table can include multiple rows for a given teacher, and I can add metadata to include whether the membership is historical or not. The question really boils down to whether I should go polymorphic or not.